# connect failed between containers with zookeeper and kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-zookeeper

I use kafka, zookeeper, elasticsearch, 3 nodes of kafka, 3 nodes of zk

I run `docker-compose.yml` on my mac,
`123.345.567` is the output of below command:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet 192'| awk '{ print $2}'
```

docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    build:
       context: /docker/zookeeper
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
       args:
         clientPort:  2181
         follow_to_leader_port: 2888
         leader_select_port:  3888
    environment:
      service1: 0.0.0.0:2888:3888
      service2: 123.345.567:2889:3889
      service3: 123.345.567:2890:3890
      clientPort: 2181
      ZOO_MY_ID:  1
      initLimit:  2
  zookeeper2:
    ports:
      - "2182:2182"
      - "2889:2889"
      - "3889:3889"
    build:
      context: /docker/zookeeper
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        clientPort:  2182
        follow_to_leader_port: 2889
        leader_select_port:  3889
    environment:
      service1: 123.345.567:2888:3888
      service2: 0.0.0.0:2889:3889
      service3: 123.345.567:2890:3890
      clientPort: 2182
      ZOO_MY_ID:  2
      initLimit:  2
  zookeeper3:
    ports:
      - "2183:2183"
      - "2890:2890"
      - "3890:3890"
    build:
      context: /docker/zookeeper
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        clientPort:  2183
        follow_to_leader_port: 2890
        leader_select_port:  3890
    environment:
      service1: 123.345.567:2888:3888
      service2: 123.345.567:2889:3889
      service3: 0.0.0.0:2890:3890
      clientPort: 2183
      initLimit:  2
      ZOO_MY_ID:  3
  kafka:
    build:
      context: /docker/kafka
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9096:9096"
    environment:
      broker_id:  1
      listeners:  PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9096
      advertised_listeners: PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9096
      zookeeper_connect:  123.345.567:2181,123.345.567:2182,123.345.567:2183/kafka_test
  kafka2:
    build:
      context: /docker/kafka
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9097:9097"
    environment:
      broker_id:  2
      listeners:  PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9097
      advertised_listeners: PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9097
      zookeeper_connect:  123.345.567:2181,123.345.567:2182,123.345.567:2183/kafka_test
  kafka3:
    build:
      context: /docker/kafka
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "9098:9098"
    environment:
      broker_id:  3
      listeners:  PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9098
      advertised_listeners: PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9098
      zookeeper_connect:  123.345.567:2181,123.345.567:2182,123.345.567:2183/kafka_test
```

docker ps output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                    NAMES
82c0f30cac77        compose_zookeeper3       "/opt/startzookeeper…"   About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:2183->2183/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2890->2890/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3890->3890/tcp   compose_zookeeper3_1
ebd93d99d0d2        compose_kafka            "/opt/startkafka.sh"     About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:9096->9096/tcp                                                   compose_kafka_1
be56ebaee602        compose_kafka2           "/opt/startkafka.sh"     About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:9097->9097/tcp                                                   compose_kafka2_1
8a68874e52f9        compose_kafka3           "/opt/startkafka.sh"     About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:9098->9098/tcp                                                   compose_kafka3_1
000a686a2772        compose_zookeeper2       "/opt/startzookeeper…"   About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:2182->2182/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2889->2889/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3889->3889/tcp   compose_zookeeper2_1
d3fc5ad9b8f8        compose_zookeeper        "/opt/startzookeeper…"   About an hour ago   Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2888->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3888->3888/tcp   compose_zookeeper_1
```

some configuration in kafka

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9097
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://123.345.567:9097
zookeeper.connect=123.345.567:2181,123.345.567:2182,123.345.567:2183/kafka_test
```

some configuration in zookeeper2

```
clientPort=2182
server.1=123.345.567:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2889:3889
server.3=123.345.567:2890:3890
```

some error log

```
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m 2018-07-15 09:54:19,083 [myid:3] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=3]/0.0.0.0:2183:FastLeaderElection@813] - New election. My id =  3, proposed zxid=0x100000047
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m 2018-07-15 09:54:19,113 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@1025] - Connection broken for id 1, my id = 3, error = 
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m java.io.EOFException
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:1010)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m 2018-07-15 09:54:19,123 [myid:3] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@1028] - Interrupting SendWorker
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m 2018-07-15 09:54:19,125 [myid:3] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=3]:FastLeaderElection@595] - Notification: 1 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x100000047 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x1 (n.peerEpoch) LOOKING (my state)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m 2018-07-15 09:54:19,126 [myid:3] - WARN  [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@941] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m java.lang.InterruptedException
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:418)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:1094)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$700(QuorumCnxManager.java:74)
[32mzookeeper3_1      |[0m  at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:929)
```

kafka

```
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,137] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 123.345.567:9096: Cannot assign requested address.
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:404)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:308)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$createAcceptorAndProcessors$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:126)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.SocketServer$$anonfun$createAcceptorAndProcessors$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:122)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptorAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:122)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:84)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:247)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:400)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m  ... 11 more
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,144] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,147] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,149] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopped socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,160] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[35mkafka_1           |[0m [2018-07-15 09:54:38,208] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

I wonder whether these containers does not need the ip:123.345.567.

Maybe they need some `inner ip` to communicate between containers?

or I need some command to check or make docker network setting?

thanks your any suggestion!

Comment: Is binding to the host IP absolutely necessary in your case? Because it would be much simpler to use `hostnames` and let the containers connect to themselves in the docker network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `123.345.567` isn't four numbers, so that's not a valid fake IP

Docker compose sets up a DNS network for you using the compose service names. You will never need the external address of your Mac inside a container.

For a fully working Compose file, [look at Confluent's](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/master/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml). Start with one Zookeeper and Broker, and get that working (Kafka won't run faster on a single machine with multiple containers because they all share one disk)

I also suggest not adding a random chroot to only one of your Zookeepers (`/kafka_test`)